# How can we describe the path of the curve $r=( t , \frac{t^2 - 1}{2} , \frac{t^2 - 1}{2})$?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I'm actually unsure of the question itself. Not sure what it is asking for, but when I graphed it, I see a parabola with increasing $x,y,z$ values as t increases.

How can one describe the continuity of the curve? It is continuous for all values of T, would that be correct?

Comment: It you mean $t$ when you are writing $T$, then it is continuous.

Comment: Note that $y = z$. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that 
$$x=t \,;\, y=\frac{t^2-1}{2} \,;\, z=\frac{t^2-1}{2}$$

Now we can change the equations without changing the curve (i.e. each step can be tracked backwards to our original description) the following way :
$$x=t \,;\, y=\frac{t^2-1}{2} \,;\, z=y \\
x=t \,;\, y=\frac{x^2-1}{2} \,;\, z=y \\
y=\frac{x^2-1}{2} \,;\, z=y \\
2y=x^2-1 \,;\, z=y \\
$$

Now, $2y=x^2-1$ is a parabola in plane, and hence a parabolic sheet in space (i.e. a vertical plane curbed by this parabola). $z=y$ is a plane. Our curve is the intersection between those two surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you just look at the $x$ and $y$ values (ignoring $z$), you get a definite parabola, vertical in orientation, open upwards and with vertex at the point $(0,-\frac 12)$.

Your complete graph also has $y=z$, so instead of a parabola going "up" you have one at a $45°$ angle to the $xy$ and $xz$ planes. The vertex here is the point $(0,-\frac 12,-\frac 12)$.

All the coordinates are continuous functions in $t$, so the entire curve is continuous.

More could be said in a description, such as the focal point of the parabola, but this is probably enough.